# Changing the order of elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation

I have a list of the form `list1 = {1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6}` and I would like to replace each of the elements in the position of represented by the previous number in the list, for instance replace 1 in position 6, 3 in position 1, 4 in position 3, 2 in position 4 and so on. In the end I should get a list of the form `{3, 5, 4, 2, 6, 1}`. I am trying to do the following:

```
A = ConstantArray[0, Length[list1]]
NewList = 
  Table[
    ReplacePart[
      A, 
      (If[Position[list1, i] - 1 != 0, 
         Position[list1, i] - 1, 
         Position[List1, Last[List1]]) -> i], 
    {i, Range[Length[List1]]}]
```

I am using `If` inside `ReplacePart` to consider the case when an element is in position 1 and send it to the position of the last element of the permutation. However, this methos is not working. Could anyone tell me why? Is there is a more efficient method to solve this problem?

Comment: The `If` expression in your code seems to be missing a `]` at its end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
newList = list1 = {1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6};
newList[[RotateRight[list1]]] = list1;
newList
```

==>   {3, 5, 4, 2, 6, 1}

Comment: Thanks! This solves my problem completely, but would you mind explaining the second line of the code? I don't really see what it is doing.

Comment: @user41116 The second line exposes a very useful purpose of `Part` by being able to `Set` arbitrary parts of a list at one time. By rotating the list right, you get `{6, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5}` and are essentially setting `newlist[[6]] = 1`, `newlist[[1]] = 3` etc...

Answer (score 3):

`Ordering[]` is another opportunity:

```
list1 = {1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6};
newList = list1[[Ordering[RotateRight[list1]]]]
(*{3, 5, 4, 2, 6, 1}*)
```

Comment: Could you explain whi the expression list1[[Ordering[RotateRight[list1]]]] actually changes list1? I don't see how it is working. THanks!